Contradiction in Euler Angle Rotation Matrix Calculation
Contradiction in Euler Angle Rotation Matrix Calculation
The Setup
Assume that I have an object in 3D space. Its orientation is defined by the transform below:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As can be seen, the object’s local axes align with the world’s axes, so the object’s transform is an identity matrix.
The First Rotation
Now, I will first rotate the object around the X axis by multiplying the object’s transform with the rotation matrix below:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\psi) & -\sin(\psi) \\
0 & \sin(\psi) & \cos(\psi) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As can be seen, the matrix presented above is a rotation matrix around the X axis, and $$\psi$$ is the amount of rotation around the X axis. Here, I ask which X axis will the first rotation rotate the object around: the object’s local X axis or the world X axis? The answer is that since the object’s local axes align with the world’s axes, the first rotation is a rotation around both the object’s local X axis and the world X axis.
The Second Rotation
Now, I will do another rotation operation by multiplying the object’s transform with another rotation matrix presented below:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & \sin(\theta) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As can be seen, the matrix presented above is a rotation matrix around the Y axis, and $$\theta$$ is the amount of rotation around the Y axis. Here, I ask again which Y axis will this second rotation rotate the object around: the object’s local Y axis or the world Y axis? Keep in mind that after the first rotation, the object’s local Y axis and the world’s Y axis are no longer aligned, so which Y axis is the second rotation around?
According to many textbooks, papers, and YouTube math tutorials, the answer is that the second rotation will be around the object’s local Y axis. However, my calculation below conflicts with this answer.
$$
M = R_y(\theta) R_x(\psi) O \quad \text{where} \quad \theta = 18^\circ, \psi = 22.2^\circ, O \text{ is the starting transform of the object, and } M \text{ is the final result}
$$
$$
R_y(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(18^\circ) & 0 & \sin(18^\circ) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin(18^\circ) & 0 & \cos(18^\circ) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
R_x(\psi) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(22.2^\circ) & -\sin(22.2^\circ) \\
0 & \sin(22.2^\circ) & \cos(22.2^\circ) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
O = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
0.951 & 0.116759 & 0.2861 \\
0 & 0.92587 & -0.37784 \\
-0.3090 & 0.359347 & 0.880555 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The fact that you see zero in $$M_{21}$$ (second row, first column) suggests that the second rotation rotates the object around the world’s Y axis, NOT the object’s local Y axis. As can be seen, my calculation contradicts the math in many textbooks and papers.
Using Godot, I had verified the fact that if the second rotation is around the object’s local Y axis, the correct result should be as shown below:
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
0.951057 & 0 & 0.309017 \\
0.116759 & 0.925871 & -0.359348 \\
-0.28611 & 0.377841 & 0.880555 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Please explain why this contradiction happens.

Please have mercy, I don't know the rule, and I didn't format the post using MathJax. I am sorry, but please don't down vote my post please. I had edited the post to show the correct format.

@that's what it is,  Sorry for accusing you of downvoting my post, and thank you so much for the upvote. By the way, do you know the answer to my question? I have been thinking for 2 days, and it is stopping my game development, please help me, very please.

Who says that $R_y(\theta) R_x(\psi)$ gives the transformation of rotation around the object's $x$ axis and then the object's $y$ axis? It's obviously world $x$ and then world $y$, although as you point out that's equivalent to object $x$ and then world $y$.

Hi David, thank you so very much for your reply. In this Youtude Video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Zjf95Jw2UE, at around the time of 5:11, the professor in the video said the second rotation will be around the object's local Y axis, not the world's Y axis. May you please help me verify with your calculation if the professor is correct? Thank you for help.

In that video, the rotation by angle $\psi$ is the last rotation, not the first. You have simply misinterpreted the video and put the matrices in the wrong sequence in your multiplication. There is a correct answer below.
